# Linefeeds in zend framework controlloer response

Tags: zend-framework

I m using zend modular structure.Every controller action returns result with extra \n at end.
When i comment line 'resources.modules[] =' in application.ini, response from controller actions is proper but after reloading page modules are not working.

For eg. echo 'here' returns as '\n here'.

can anyone help me come out of wit this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you have plugins, action helpers.. and use the preDispatch or any ...dispatch method at all. Make sure that these does not echo any \n. 
Basically by using resources.modules[]= "" loads all the modules bootstraps files.